# What does a colon mean on a directory in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, directory

I'm reading a book about nodejs/express and I'm trying to reproduce the examples.
I've never seen a colon on a directory name, but I've seen it a couple of times in this book. Could you tell me what it means?

This is the example I saw:

```
app.post('/contest/vacation-photo/:year/:month', function(req, res){
```

Comment: That's a URL pattern.  It has nothing to do with directories.

Comment: @SLaks what does the colon mean, then? does it work only with year and month keyword or with any other word?

Comment: SLaks is right, but for what it's worth, on Linux filenames can contain colons and the character has no special meaning to the OS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As SLaks stated, it's a URL pattern, the colon means that you want to receive the URL segments as parameter, here is an example

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(request, response){
  response.send('user ' + request.params.id);
});
```

in this example, if you will send a get request to the URL www.server.com/user/mike, the request.params.id will be set to mike.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the `:year` or `:month`, there are URL parameters. You can get back with [req.params](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params).

For exemple to get back this two arguments you can do something like :

```
app.post('/contest/vacation-photo/:year/:month', function(req, res){
    // Get the year url parameter :
    var year = req.params.year;
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: So the real url would be something like `'/contest/vacation-photo/15/2'` ?

Comment: Yes, and `15` and `2` will be your parameters `:year` and `:month`